migrating jenkins - jobs failing after
I migrated jenkins 2.373 which was on azure vm (centos) to a new azure vm (ubuntu jammy) .
jenkins is started and i am seeing everything. the jobs, the user, the plugins…
but the jobs pass only until a certain stage, mostly untill the end of build and then they fail.
I backed up the jenkins home directory with a filesystem snapshot. il was on a separate volume.
I attached the new separate volume containing the jenkins home directory to the new vm.
i mounted it on the vm and i made a symbolic link between /var/lib/jenkins and /mnt/storage/lib/jenkins.
though i have to note that both of my jenkins, old and new are running. and they are connected to the same bitbucket. i don’t know though if this is causing the problem
is ther anything else i need to back up or install on the new vm ?

What error do they fail with?

what went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':auto-testing:jib'.

com.google.cloud.tools.jib.plugins.common.BuildStepsExecutionException: Build image failed, perhaps you should make sure your credentials for 'smarttest.azurecr.io/cron/autotesting/dev' are set up correctly.
while i connect to azure with :


az login
az acr login --name smarttest
the tests starts to pass successfully. but what can i do to make this permanent ? because each time that i exit the vm , it stops working


Did you use the credentials plugin in the old one & do you use it in the new one now?

yes, i have the credentials saved in the previous jenkins. and i have them all in the new one. though i don't understand why it's not working

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I resolved the issue. since my jenkins used docker, i had to give the correct authentication to docker. so i added the auth in ~/.docker/config.json .
and the jobs started passing perfectly.
